# Set schedule for Azure Logic App to run once a week

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure Logic app that dynamically gets Blob contents from my azure storage account and sends an email with the attachment. I want to set a schedule for my logic app to run once a week.
Any idea how I can achieve this?

Here's my current workflow:

[image: Here's my current workflow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for Recurrence trigger's.
It's possible to set something like time triggers from regular Azure Functions.

Here's instruction how to create one in your logic app.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-recurrence

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you are trying to do.  If you want to get an email every time your blob is updated, your current Logic App is the way to go.  If you change the trigger to a Reccurrence trigger as [Rob Ert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9139691/rob-ert) stated than you could potentially lose updates (the blob could have many updates in a week).  If you don't care about the individual updates, then Reccurrence is the proper trigger.

Comment: `If you want to get an email every time your blob is updated, your current Logic App is the way to go` -- Are you sure that this is right? I have a similar setup and yet the Logic App runs once successfully and then stops despite continued changes made to the blob storage.